# Synergy 'Shift' key not working on the Mac

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, synergy, shift

I have Synergy server on a Windows 7 box, and a Mac client connected to it. Most keys work fine, except for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on the right side. The left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key works just fine but not the one on the right side.

Does anybody have the same issue, and what is the resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that downgrading a windows 7 server to 1.3.4 fixes the problem. On the Windows 7 server I tried every server up through 1.4.2 beta and none of them fixed the problem. On OSX 10.6 client I  tried everything up through the 1.4.2 beta and none of the newer versions solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with the issue at work until my good friend Paul Udruscu pointed out that I can use [KeyTweek](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) on Windows, to remap the right shift key to the left one and alleviate the issue altogether.

Comment: Good workaround, i'm using it with 1.4.6 Beta on all nodes

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as well. Saves me from having to downgrade to the 1.3.8 version of Synergy which is a significant downgrade.

Comment: The link to keytweek doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This is logged in the synergy bug list here: http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/2842 so yes, lots of people have the same issue.

They don't seem to come closer to fixing this however.

Comment: Still broken as of May 2012 :-/

Answer (score 2):

Going off the workaround above by Ash, this can also be accomplished by adding a registry value to Keyboard Layout. It remaps the left shift key to the right shift key.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
New binary value
Name: Scancode Map
Value: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 2a 00 36 00 00 00 00 00

Reference: modified [this example](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista); worked on Windows 7 with Synergy 1.4.8.

Comment: This works great.  Note that it requires a reboot after you make the registry key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 1.3.6 by any chance? I just ran into the same problem between a Windows 7 server and Mac OS 10.6 client, exactly as you describe.

I installed the 1.3.7 nightly build (902 specifically) from http://synergy-foss.org/packages/ on both ends, and the problem appears to be fixed.

Edit: scratch that, the problem is back. Going to try a few more things...

Comment: I downgraded my server back to 1.3.4 and that solved the problem. Client on Mac is fine as 1.3.6.

Comment: Yup, taking the server back to 1.3.4 fixed it. I tried going all the way forward to 1.5 nightly, but no dice. Thanks!